# Best way to set image region to zeros in OpenCV C++?

Tags: c++, opencv

I would like to ask which is the most efficient way to set a region of a grayscale Mat image to zeros (or any other constant value, for that matter).

Should I create a zeros image and then use `copyTo()` or is there a better way?

Comment: use calloc(0, sizeof(Mat))

Comment: @DebasishJana Not a good idea. `calloc` is not a C++ function and your suggestion doesn't take any account of the fact that `sizeof(Mat)` is not the size of the image data it contains. Bad suggestion for so many reasons, sorry.

Comment: Well, then use a constructor to initialize the underlying memory with a proper class.

Comment: @DebasishJana `cv::Mat` *is* a "proper class", it seems you don't know OpenCV?

Comment: got it, thanks @RogerRowland, from http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html#cv-mat-zeros, use cv::Mat m = cv::Mat::zeros(height, width, CV_32F);

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would use [`setTo()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=setto#Mat&%20Mat%3a%3asetTo%28InputArray%20value,%20InputArray%20mask%29), for example:

```
// load an image
cv::Mat pImage = cv::imread("someimage.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

// select a region of interest
cv::Mat pRoi = pImage(cv::Rect(10, 10, 20, 20));

// set roi to some rgb colour   
pRoi.setTo(cv::Scalar(blue, green, red));
```

Comment: Actually it is `cv::Scalar(blue, green, red)`, see http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor

Answer (score 5):

Let's say we paint a black rectangle in a white canvas:

```
    cv::Mat img(100,100,CV_8U,cv::Scalar(255));
    img(cv::Rect(15,15,20,40))=0;
    cv::imshow("Img",img);
    cv::waitKey();
```

Comment: Is it correct that this only works with matrices on the stack?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
Mat image;
image = imread("images/lena.jpg");
int x=100;int y=100; int w=100; int h=100;
Rect roi = Rect(x,y,w,h);
image(roi).setTo(cv::Scalar(0,0,0));
imshow("display",image);
```

Comment: How is this any different from Roger Rowland's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24754383/369450)?

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.